# External table is not in the expected format - But works if I open and close the file

Tags: excel, vb.net

I am trying to read and excel file but I get the "External table is not in the expected format" error.

If I open and close the xls file and rerun it works.  I'm sure this is problem with the customer's data, but because it worked before a recent patch, they are unwilling to look into the issue.

I have tried these connection strings.  They work only after I open and close the file myself.

`"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & xlsPath & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0"""
"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & xlsPath & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1"""
"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & xlsPath & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;"""`

Has anyone else run into this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Going to vote to close as `off-topic:  cannot be reproduced`.  I'm hopeful that someone can chime in on their experience, but in general this is A) a discussion piece (out of scope for SO), and B) may require looking at the actual files/data which wouldn't be reproducible by the SO community with the provided info.  As B is kind of the overarching issue, where A could be rectified, my vote was reflective.

Comment: If you open the file in a text editor, do you see plain text (like a CSV file), or perhaps HTML, or is it definitely binary data?

Comment: It is binary data.  This is sparked me to do a compare on the file before and after opening.  I do see some change in the binary.